# Mysql query is not working when executed after few minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure about what's happening, but it seems like it's because of waiting time.
so when i execute this page to do a video conversion. First mysql query works, but then after few minutes mysql query will not work. it doesn't happen when converting a small file(shorter conversion time)

mysql works

```
$db->query("UPDATE temporary SET used='1' WHERE hash='$hash'");
```

//wait for ffmpeg convert

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i $input -threads 10 -preset medium -vf 'scale=-1:270, scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:270' -map 0 -movflags +faststart -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 $output");
```

//mysql will not work

```
$db->query("UPDATE temporary SET used='1' WHERE hash='$hash'");
```

//this still work here

```
unlink($dir.$file);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "will not work"? The connection? The query? Have you checked the logfiles?

Comment: i'm not getting any logfiles for that. I know that when it's taking too long for php execution to reach the sql query again after the ffmpeg conversion it will not work. so it's most likely the connection?

Comment: who knows! You definitely can activate log files to dig deeper into the issue. There are a lot of things involved in a sql query, and any of it can fail. HAve you checked php error_log? the server console? mysql logs?

Comment: SET GLOBAL wait_timeout= '3600'
this actually did the job
it was the mysql connection close time

Comment: mind that you are hijacking the connection inneccessarily. You'd better close the connection, do the video transcoding, then open a new one to do the update. db Connections are a very precious and limited resource!

Comment: that's what i did before.. isnt it gonna take load time to reconnect to sql again?

Comment: well it depends, it shouldn't if the db is configured properly as it would use a **connection pool** and you're just giving back a connection so other requests can use it, but in any case it'd be much better than to keep it open for a very long time when you dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better idea of what's going on when you are running your queries execute this on the console:

```
mysql> show full processlist;
```

If you have a ton of queries running and you want to narrow down the list then user the Pager like so:

```
mysql> pager grep "<your sql query string>";
mysql> show full processlist;
```

I hope this helps narrow down the issue!

More info:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html